# Date with the correct time

Tags: php, date, time

I used date to get the date but...

It's 3 hours off from my computer time.

This `date('g:i A')`

Is giving a time EST I believe because I'm PST and it's 3 hours off.

Is there a way to get it to put the correct time zone automatically?

Comment: you'll have to define better what you mean by "the correct" time zone.  Correct for whom?  If it's "whomever is looking at my web site", then you will have to ask them for *their* time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply get the time 3 hours from the server you can say:

```
date ('g:i A', time () + 60*60*3);
```

or

```
date ('g:i A', time () - 60*60*3);
```

To my knowledge there is not a "perfect" way to get the timezone a user is in, but in the past I have used javascript to find out the user's current computer time and compare that to the server's time. Javascript is the only method I know of for getting any information related to someone's current time or timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the timezone in your configuration file (`php.ini`) or at run time. PHP is a server side application, so it can't "automatically" get the time zone from the client.

[Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)

If you're working with data, you should use UTC date/time and offset the time appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The robust solution is to use `DateTime` with `DateTimeZone` instead of `date`:

```
<?php

$date = new \DateTime(null, new \DateTimezone('PST'));
// or even better: 
$date = new \DateTime(null, new \DateTimezone('America/Los_Angeles'));

$formatted = $date->format('g:i A');
```

Note that just using a generic timezone such as 'PST' may still be ambiguous. Some locations in that timezone may be observing DST, some may not. Thus, the only reliable thing to do is to specify the location as concrete as possible.